# show content based on width of parent with css

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

IS it possible to show certain content with css based on the width of the parent div?  I was thinking something along the lines of media queries but I don't want the whole device width just the width of the parent div.

I can do it with jQuery [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/dFB2s/) (change the < to > to see different content), but was wondering if there was a way to do something similar with css3?

```
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="content">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td><span class="full">BAHRAIN</span><span class="abbrev">BHR</span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><span class="full">BELGIUM</span><span class="abbrev">BEL</span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><span class="full">EGYPT</span><span class="abbrev">EGY</span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><span class="full">LITHUANIA</span><span class="abbrev">LTU</span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><span class="full">SWEDEN</span><span class="abbrev">SWE</span></td></tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        var w = $('#parent').width();
        console.log('width: ', w);
        if (w<200) 
        {
        $("#content").addClass("showsmall");
        }
        </script>

        <style>
        #parent {width: 300px;}
        .abbrev {display:none;}
        .showsmall .abbrev {display:block;}
        .showsmall .full {display:none;}
        </style>
```

Comment: CSS can only check the viewport dimensions via media queries, not the dimensions of any particular element.  Have you met the `<abbr>` tag?  http://cssdeck.com/labs/ovzhnmfa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.width` will never accept IF, because you set `width` in css to `200px`

If you want to see it dynamic you shoud:

- Replace `width` to `max-width` in CSS
- Add `.resize` event

**code**:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var w = $('#parent').width();
    console.log('width: ', w);
    if (w < 200) {
        $("#content").addClass("showsmall");
    } else {
        $("#content").removeClass("showsmall");
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dFB2s/2/)

Answer (score -1):

This what do you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dFB2s/2/). **This is a solution using only CSS.**

If you set the `width` literally, you won't able to leave to browser adjust the size automatically.

I changed a bit the markup with the object to make the example more easy:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span class="text">
            This is a normal text.
        </span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="fixed-child">
        <span class="text">
            This is a text very laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge!
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.parent > div {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: .325em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As you see, I set the `height` to make the example look better.

Be good,
Leonardo